# How can I remove nodes specified in one XML file from another XML file?

Tags: xml, powershell

My goal is to have a PowerShell script executed as a scheduled task to clean several XML log files and reformat into more usable XML datasets. Below is just an small snippet of the bigger project.

LogFile(Sample):

```xml
<ImportError>
    <ErrorMessage></ErrorMessage>
    <RejectedRecord>
      <!--Original Data-->
      <DataToDelete2 ImportMode="Set" MatchingFields="Int6">
        <!--Error: -->
        <SomthingsChanged></SomthingsChanged>
        <Disabled>FALSE</Disabled>
        <FirstName>Joe</FirstName>
        <LastName>Biden</LastName>
        <DataToDelete1></DataToDelete1>
        <DataToDelete1 ImportMode="Set" MatchingFields="BadgeInt1" />
      </DataToDelete2>
    </RejectedRecord>
  </ImportError>
  <ImportError>
    <ErrorMessage></ErrorMessage>
    <RejectedRecord>
      <!--Original Data-->
      <DataToDelete2 ImportMode="Set" MatchingFields="Int6">
        <!--Error: -->
        <SomthingsChanged></SomthingsChanged>
        <Disabled>FALSE</Disabled>
        <FirstName>Stephen</FirstName>
        <LastName>Hawking</LastName>
        <DataToDelete1></DataToDelete1>
        <DataToDelete1 ImportMode="Set" MatchingFields="BadgeInt1" />
      </DataToDelete2>
    </RejectedRecord>
  </ImportError>
  <ImportError>
    <ErrorMessage>SomeJunk</ErrorMessage>
    <RejectedRecord>
      <!--Original Data-->
      <DataToDelete2 ImportMode="Set" MatchingFields="Int6">
        <!--Error: SomeJunk-->
        <Int6>abcdefg</Int6>
        <SomthingsChanged>Blue|Black|Yellow|Red|Green|Orange|Brown|Purple</SomthingsChanged>
        <Disabled>FALSE</Disabled>
        <Text1>text1</Text1>
        <FirstName>Bill</FirstName>
        <LastName>Gates</LastName>
        <DataToDelete1 ImportMode="Set" MatchingFields="BadgeInt1">
          <BadgeNumber>1234</BadgeNumber>
          <BadgeInt1>69696969</BadgeInt1>
        </DataToDelete1>
      </DataToDelete2>
    </RejectedRecord>
  </ImportError>
```

I have setup an INI file for users to modify. The intent is to allow the script to be a bit more flexible to deal with other XML log files. Here is a very small sample for this purpose.

INI(sample):

```xml
<Config>
    <AppSettings>
        <FilePath>ControlFiles</FilePath>
        <LogFile>JunkFile.xml</LogFile>
        <optFile>flf_</optFile>
    </AppSettings>

    <remLine id="1">RejectedRecord</remLine>
    <remline id="2">DataToDelete2</remline>
    <remline id="3">DataToDelete1</remline>
    <remline id="4">&lt;!--</remline>
</Config>
```

Now for where I'm looking for a bit of guidance, I want to loop through the `remLine` nodes of the INI file and set them into a `$remLines` variable that can be used later on in the script:

```powershell
Get-content "$appDir\$filePath\$logFile" | Select-String -NotMatch ($remlines)
```

Instead of what's hard-coded now:

```powershell
Get-content "$appDir\$filePath\$logFile" | Select-String -NotMatch ("Get-content "$appDir\$filePath\$logFile" | Select-String -NotMatch ("DataToDelete2","RejectedRecord","DatatToDelete1","<!--")
```

Sample PowerShell script:

```powershell
#-------------------------------------------------- LogFile Formatter --------------------------------------------------#
#
#          LogFormatter cleans and formats Import Error Logs to be used in PowerBI Dataset
#
#--------------------------------------------------                   --------------------------------------------------#
#------------------------------------------------- Set Basic Variables -------------------------------------------------#

$tStamp = Get-Date -Format "MMddyy_HHmm"
$appDir = ($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
$ScrptName = Split-Path -Path "$appDir" -Leaf
$appDir = Split-Path -Path "$appDir" -Parent
#------------------------------------------------ Set Variables From XML -----------------------------------------------#

[xml]$appINI = Get-Content "$appDir\App_.ini"   

$lfPath = $appINI.Config.AppSettings.FilePath
$logFile = $appINI.Config.AppSettings.LogFile
$optFName = $appINI.Config.AppSettings.optFile
$ffName = "$fName$tStamp.xml"

#-------------------------------- Help needed Here 
#loop through appINI.remLine(s)
foreach ($remLine in $appINI.Config.remLine) {
  Write-Host $remLine.'#text'
  }

#--------------------------------

$outFile = Get-content "$appDir\$filePath\$logFile" | Select-String -NotMatch ("DataToDelete2","RejectedRecord","DataToDelete1")


$outFile | Out-File -FilePath "$appDir\$filePath\$ffName.xml"
```

Sample output file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ImportErrorS>
  <ImportError>
    <ErrorMessage></ErrorMessage>
    <SomthingsChanged></SomthingsChanged>
    <Disabled>FALSE</Disabled>
    <FirstName>Joe</FirstName>
    <LastName>Biden</LastName>
  </ImportError>
  <ImportError>
    <ErrorMessage></ErrorMessage>
    <SomthingsChanged></SomthingsChanged>
    <Disabled>FALSE</Disabled>
    <FirstName>Stephen</FirstName>
    <LastName>Hawking</LastName>
  </ImportError>
  <ImportError>
    <ErrorMessage>SomeJunk</ErrorMessage>
    <Int6>abcdefg</Int6>
    <SomthingsChanged>Blue|Black|Yellow|Red|Green|Orange|Brown|Purple</SomthingsChanged>
    <Disabled>FALSE</Disabled>
    <Text1>text1</Text1>
    <FirstName>Bill</FirstName>
    <LastName>Gates</LastName>
    <BadgeNumber>1234</BadgeNumber>
    <BadgeInt1>69696969</BadgeInt1>
  </ImportError>
</ImportErrorS>
```

Please be mindful this is just an excerpt of a much bigger project and this is the piece I am wrestling with to be more flexible for various log files, and general XML cleanup. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `$remLines = $appIni.Config.remLine."#text"`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think to try the obvious, but this did it.  No need for the loop at all. The way that it was appearing in the console I did not think that was going to work without looping through the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Try following.  Instead of deleting create a new document and put what you need into the new document :

```
using assembly System
using assembly System.Collections
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$inputFilename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$outputFilename = "c:\temp\test1.xml"

$ident = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?><ImportErrors></ImportErrors>"
$xNewDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Parse($ident)
$xNewImportErrors = $xNewDoc.Root

$xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)
$root = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]$xDoc.Root

$importErrors = $root.Descendants("ImportError")

foreach($importError in $importErrors)
{
   $xNewImportError = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::Parse("<ImportError/>")
   $xNewImportErrors.Add($xNewImportError)
   $xNewImportError.Add($importError.Element("ErrorMessage"))
   $dataToDelete2 = $importError.Descendants("DataToDelete2")

   $nodes =  $dataToDelete2.Elements()
   $xNewImportError.Add($nodes)
}
$xNewDoc.Save($outputFilename)
```